# Undefined method 'visit' (using rspec and capybara)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

Upon trying to run a specs files for integration testing, I see:

```
undefined method `visit' for #<Class:0xab9a140> (NoMethodError)
```

I've searched this website and found out several solutions to my problems, and these are the **solutions I've tried already** ( with no success ):

- added file under spec/features instead of spec/requests (they have always been there)
- add `include Capybara::DSL` to my spec file - this is funny. When I add this, I stop having the aforementioned error and start having **another error message**:

  - `undefined method 'expect' for #<Class:0x9d2a088> (NoMethodError)`
- replacing `describe` with `feature` in the spec tests. (no change)

Outcome of trying to run the specs which contain the `visit` method:

```
felipe@felipe-VirtualBox:~/rails/project-manager$ bundle exec rspec spec/features/
No DRb server is running. Running in local process instead ...
/home/felipe/rails/project-manager/spec/features/projects_spec.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined method `visit' for #<Class:0xab9a140> (NoMethodError)
from /home/felipe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:246:in `module_eval'
from /home/felipe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:246:in `subclass'
from /home/felipe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:232:in `describe'
from /home/felipe/rails/project-manager/spec/features/projects_spec.rb:14:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /home/felipe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:246:in `module_eval'
from /home/felipe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:246:in `subclass'
from /home/felipe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:232:in `describe'
from /home/felipe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/dsl.rb:18:in `describe'
from /home/felipe/rails/project-manager/spec/features/projects_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/felipe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load'
from /home/felipe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `block in load_spec_files'
from /home/felipe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `each'
from /home/felipe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load_spec_files'
from /home/felipe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
from /home/felipe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:77:in `rescue in run'
from /home/felipe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:73:in `run'
from /home/felipe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

**my Gemfile:**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.1'

group :development,:test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'pg','0.15.1'
  gem 'watchr'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'spork-rails'
  gem 'guard-spork'
  gem 'childprocess'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.1'

gem 'uglifier', '>= 2.1.0'

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.1'

gem 'jquery-rails','3.0.4'

gem 'turbolinks','1.1.1'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

**My spec_helper.rb file**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'

Spork.prefork do
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
  require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'rspec/autorun'

  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

  ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)

  RSpec.configure do |config|

    config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

    config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

    config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

    config.order = "random"
    # Disable the old-style object.should syntax.
    config.expect_with :rspec do |c|
       c.syntax = :expect
    end
  end
end

Spork.each_run do

end
```

**the actual test (yes, it's under `spec/features` folder)**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Projects" do
  describe "Projects index" do

    it "should show the string 'Projetos'" do

      visit '/projects'
      expect(page).to have_content('Projetos')

    end
  end

  describe 'Add and delete a project' do

    visit '/projects/new'

    expect(page).to have_content('Novo')

  end 

end
```

**I'm looking for suggestions and pointers as to what might be my issue.**

**P.S.:** I'm running  `rails (4.0.1)`, `capybara (2.2.0)`, `rspec-core (2.14.7)` `rspec-rails (2.14.0)`

Comment: It doesn't look like you're explicitly requiring `capybara` or `capybara/rails` in your `spec_helper.rb` file.  Have you tried doing that?  The most recent `README` lists to do so here: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#using-capybara-with-rspec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the problem.... I was missing a `it ... do ... end` block around the second call to `visit`... Sorry for this and thank you to everyone who's helped me.

Comment: No need to apologize. I should have seen it. I checked for that situation on your first `visit` call, but didn't check further down in your code. Moral for me is to ask which line the stacktrace pointed to. You might want to include that info next time. :-)